# back button restriction on the app

Tags: codenameone

I am looking to restrict the back button i.e it does not  do anything. For that I found that we need to override in StateMachine Class.

```
protected boolean allowBackTo(String formName) {
   return false;}
```

On our development we deleted this class and we don't have this class.

So is there any way to restrict this back button in the total application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the statemachine class in a GUIBuilder app. If you deleted it and are no longer using the GUIBuilder then this code would no longer be relevant anyway and is totally unnecessary as back is added manually.